# Run app widget - Could not identify launch activity

Tags: android, android-appwidget

In AndroidStudio i create a new android project an create a app widget and choose option for configuration activity. AndroidStudio generates now the provider-info xml, the declerations in manifest xml an the both java classes. One activity, one widget provider.

This should be runnable but i get error: Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found. Error while Launching activity. The launch field also shows a red cross.

I dont understand why because there is no default activity. The configuration activity should start when the widget provider start working. To do so there is a intent-filter for the activitiy with android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE.

I add also categroy in intent-filter LAUNCHER and DEFAULT. In provider and in activity. But still get the error message.

If I choose "Nothing" in launch configuration and I run the app it brings only many  error messages: Waiting for application to come online: com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication | com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication.test

But the widget isnt installed and doesnt run. What doing Im wrong? I try out Intellij and AndroidStudio.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**widget_info.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/new_app_widget"
    android:configure="com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication.NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/new_app_widget">
</appwidget-provider>
```

And there are the two Java classes.

---

---

**EDIT1:**

Now I add category LAUNCHER and action MAIN:

```
<activity android:name=".NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I start the debugger sometimes the widget ist in the widget store and sometimes not.

I also see that in the generated java activity class is a finish method called:

```
// If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
    finish();
    return;
}
```

But it also doesnt work if I delete thid. I dont unterstand why a the default google example not work.

Here are the java classes:

**Activity:**

```
package com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * The configuration screen for the {@link NewAppWidget NewAppWidget} AppWidget.
 */
public class NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    EditText mAppWidgetText;
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication.NewAppWidget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";

    public NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        setContentView(R.layout.new_app_widget_configure);
        mAppWidgetText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.appwidget_text);
        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mAppWidgetText.setText(loadTitlePref(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this, mAppWidgetId));
    }

    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Context context = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

            // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
            String widgetText = mAppWidgetText.getText().toString();
            saveTitlePref(context,mAppWidgetId,widgetText);

            // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            NewAppWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    };

    // Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
        prefs.apply();
    }

    // Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
    // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null) {
            return titleValue;
        } else {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        }
    }

    static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
        prefs.apply();
    }
}
```

**And Provider:**

```
package com.example.desktop_win10.myapplication;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 * App Widget Configuration implemented in {@link NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity}
 */
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Default Activity not found.` is very clearly the problem. When you add the default intent, what is the error? Also, I'm sorry you wasted your time, but switching IDEs does not change how the code is compiled

Comment: @cricket_007 Problem is, there is no default activity, because it is a widget project without any activities. The provider should start the only one (configuration activity) by action intent-filter android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

?

As I know, without it android won't know which activity to launch as the main activity.

Comment: No not exactly. But now I try out on provider - doesn work. Why can not choose "Nothing" in launch configuration? And in the activity would be the wrong place because I declare the android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE which should start the configuration activity.  Now i dispite try it out in activity: After three trials it works so far (it works infrequent).

Comment: Now the app is installed but console shows: Waiting for application to come online. Handy shows: Waiting for debugger ... Force..? Waiting little time the Activity starts and ends directly. Application is now installed but widget not. I dont know why but after 4 trials now the widget is in the widget menu. But when i add it to homescreen the debugger dont register it.

Comment: Did you try to use "Invalidate and Clear Caches"?